# Implicit Adaptive Payments aren't generating IPNs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm sending money from one account to another using Adaptive Payments API. I'm using the 
active_paypal_adaptive_payment gem to simplify things a bit. So far I've got everything working as desired but my payments aren't generating IPNs.

I'm implicitly sending the payments, i.e. from 'my' account to another so this doesn't require the user to approve the payment via paypal. This is going to be an issue if the payments are pending or have other issues. Is there some sort of option I've missed?

Comment: Before anyone asks, I have disabled the Payment Review option

Answer (score 0):

OK - figured it out, I was setting the notification url with

```
  :notify_url => ipn_url,
```

rather than

```
  :ipn_notification_url => ipn_url
```

Still, I'm surprised it didn't use the ipn location defined in the profile.